# EJB transaction isolation levels

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0

Considering we have some ejb's and their transaction settings are :

ejb1 starts doing work with the Requires_New attribute and calls ejb2 which has also requires new attribute on its side.

My question is...if ejb2's transaction fails...will ejb1's transaction fail too ? I suspect not.

Any answers are welcome.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't rollback *if you catch the exception thrown by the call to ejb2*.

Answer (score 2):

No, `ejb1` transaction will not fail as long as (assuming exception is the cause) the exception thrown from `ejb2` will not be thrown from `ejb1` as well. In this case it will rollback `ejb1` independently.